# Calculate $\int_{{{\mathbb R}_+}^2} (x^2-y) \cdot e^{-x-y}\, dy\, dx$ while supposed to be splitting up the integrand

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I'm having trouble calculating

$$ \int_{{{\mathbb R}_+}^2}  (x^2-y) \cdot e^{-x-y}\, dy\, dx $$

while supposed to be using

$$ \int_{\mathbb R}  \int_{\mathbb R} f(y)f(x)\, dy\, dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(y)\, dy  \cdot \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\, dx $$

But how would I split the integrand

$$(x^2-y) \cdot e^{-x-y} = x^2e^{-x}e^{-y} - ye^{-x}e^{-y}$$

into $f(x)$ and $f(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$ (x^2-y) \cdot \exp(-x-y)\, dy\, dx =x^2e^{-x}e^{-y}dxdy- ye^{-x}e^{-y})  dy\, dx$$

But $$\iint_{{{\Bbb R}_+}^2} ye^{-x}e^{-y}  dy\, dx =\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy\right)\left(\int_0^\infty ye^{-y}dy\right) = 1$$

and  $$\iint_{{{\Bbb R}_+}^2} x^2e^{-x}e^{-y}  dy\, dx =\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy\right)\left(\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-y}dy\right) = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate with respect to one variable first either $x$ or $y$ and then with the other. Integrate both from in range $(0, \infty )$. Also you will need to use integration by parts.